# h2 database garbling Japanese text when loading from CSV in Windows but not on Linux

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I've got a Spring Boot project that loads some data into h2 database from a CSV file which contains English and Japanese text. The Japanese text loads fine when I run the application on Linux (CentOs7) but when I run it on Windows I get garbled text.

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = new Csv().read("classpath:suru.csv", null, null);
    while (rs.next()) {
        conjugations.add(
            new TranslationPair(
                rs.getString(SOURCE_LANGUAGE),
                rs.getString(TARGET_LANGUAGE)
            )
        );
    }

    rs.close();

} catch(SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've tried setting the charset options like:

```
ResultSet rs = new Csv().read("classpath:suru.csv", null, "charset=UTF-8");
```

But it just gives me slightly different garbage.

The CSV file itself is saved as UTF-8. The H2 docs mention they use Unicode. Is there some settings on the JVM I need to configure for this to work right? Curious as to why it doesn't work in my windows environment but gives the expected output under my linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution.

Have to set -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in the JRE options.

Comment: I would rather set the encoding in the thing that reads the file rather than forcing the default encoding for the whole VM (even if UTF-8 is a sensible default).

Comment: That's what I was initially trying to do by setting the setOptions() and passing in charset=UTF-8 but it only had the effect of spitting out different garbage.

So, if there is any other suggestions on where that could be set i'm all ears.